# Como recuperar apenas um arquivo específico do stash?

Tags: git

Suponhamos que eu tenha `a.txt`, `b.txt` e `c.txt` que foram modificados em um determinado branch e que eu tenha usado o comando `git stash` em todos eles para esconder as alterações.

Se eu rodar o `git stash pop`, recuperarei todos os arquivos, e eles voltaram para o trabalho atual.

Porém, eu gostaria de saber: Como posso fazer para recuperar apenas o arquivo `b.txt` armazenado através desse `git stash`, conforme o exemplo acima?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

você pode aplicar o uso de `git checkout` ou `git show` para restaurar um arquivo específico.

```
git checkout stash@{0} -- <nome do arquivo>
```

Para listar os arquivos:

```
git stash list
// stash@{0}: nome da branch que foi realizado o `stash`: Descrição
// stash@{1}: nome da branch que foi realizado o `stash`: Descrição
```

Obs.: Ao listar as entradas `stash` que você possui atualmente. Cada entrada `stash` recebe um numeração (por exemplo, `stash@{0}` é a entrada mais recente, `stash@{1}` é a anterior, etc.), o nome da ramificação que estava atual quando a entrada foi feita e um descrição curta da confirmação na qual a entrada foi baseada.

Para saber qual arquivo:

```
git stash show -p stash@{0}
```

Comment: Dei um +1. Dica... Tente explicar melhor sobre o número `0` dentro do `{n}`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters apoiado.

Comment: Não entendi o que seria o `@{0} -` e tem que ter esse hífen mesmo: `-` antes do nome do arquivo? Seria legal usar os dados do autor da resposta para colocar um exemplo tão didático quanto a pergunta

Comment: @hugocsl atualizei

Comment: @hugocsl [relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/425437/o-que-significa-o-tra%c3%a7o-duplo-sozinho-num-comando-bash)

Answer (score 0):

passo 1 : listar os stashes existentes.

```
git stash list
stash@{0}: nome da branch que foi realizado o `stash`: Descrição
stash@{1}: nome da branch que foi realizado o `stash`: Descrição
stash@{2}: nome da branch que foi realizado o `stash`: Descrição
stash@{N}: nome da branch que foi realizado o `stash`: Descrição
```

passo2: localizar o stash que possui o seu arquivo, caso seja o último sera o `stash@{0}` que vai de {0} até {n} stashes.

```
git stash show --name-only -p stash@{0}
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

`show --name-only`: exibe apenas o nome do arquivo
`show` : exibe o conteúdo do arquivo

passo 3: Recuperar o arquivo do stash.

```
git checkout stash@{0} b.txt
```