# O que significa o traço-duplo sozinho num comando Bash?

Tags: bash, sh

Tem um tempinho que uso Linux e sei que alguns comandos possuem argumentos que utilizam o `-` no início de uma palavra.

Exemplo:

```
 ls -la
```

E alguns outros, usam dois traços, assim:

```
php artisan --help
```

Porém eu já vi alguns casos onde o traço duplo é utilizado sem nenhuma palavra na frente.

Exemplo 1:

```
 git checkout master -- file.txt
```

Exemplo 2:

```
grep -- -v *
```

Exemplo 3:

```
npm run lint -- --fix
```

No caso, o `--` está separado de uma palavra, como no exemplo que dei do `--help`. Eu cheguei a pensar que isso era específico do `git`, pelo fato de ser o único comando que aprendi que precisava do `--` (como no Exemplo 1). Porém percebi que outros comandos também usam o `--`.

Sendo assim, pergunto:

O traço duplo tem algum significado especial no Bash? Ou é alguma coisa específica dos comandos citados?

Comment: Você tem um minuto para ouvir a palavra do POSIX?

Comment: Tenho. Todo ouvidos

Comment: Bem resumido,  o `--` "solto" é o "fim das flags". Dali pra frente, mesmo que algo comece com `-`, é valor literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**O traço duplo sozinho tem algum significado especial?**

Tem sim, ele indica o fim das opções do comando, fazendo com que tudo que venha após ele seja considerado operando.

**Ou é alguma coisa específica dos comandos citados?**

Não específica desses comandos, mas sim do POSIX, que é um padrão que estes comando obedecem.

POSIX é um acrônimo de *Portable Operating System Interface*, que é uma convensão (padrão) definido pela IEEE Std 1003.1-2017. É nela que é definido que as opções são indicadas com um único hífen seguido de uma letra (podendo ser agrupadas) e que com dois hifens é um nome extenso da opção. Desta forma é possível diferenciar `-Bar`, que é o mesmo que passar as três opções `-B -a -r`, de `--Bar`, que é apenas uma opção de nome extenso.

Quanto aos hifens sozinhos, define-se:

> ***Guideline 10:*** The first `--` argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the '-' character.

<sup>[Fonte](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)</sup>

Vale dar a atenção ao texto "*Any following arguments **SHOULD BE** treated as operands*". Ou seja, se o comando em questão está de acordo com o POSIX, então deve aceitar o duplo hifen como forma indicar que o restante do comando serão apenas operandos.

Então quando é feito `git checkout master -- file.txt` tudo o que vier depois do `--` será operando do comando `git checkout`, que de acordo com a documentação, possui assinatura `git checkout [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>...` (Veja `git checkout --help` para mais informações). Ou seja, tudo o que vier após o `--` será valor de `<pathspec>...`.

Também é muito útil quando o valor que você deseja passar é uma opção do comando em questão, tal como aconteceu com o `grep`, que foi passado o valor `"-v"` como operando. Nesse caso poderia imaginar um comando fictício que atua como proxy de outros comandos: `run [<options>] command [<options>...]`. Seria necessário achar uma maneira de identificar o que é opção do próprio `run` e o que será opção do `command`. Supondo que `-V` exibe a versão corrente do comando, qual é a diferença de `run -V python` e `run python -V`? A versão de quem seria exibida? Já ao fazer `run -- python -V` não há redundância, dado que agora o `-V` será passado como operando do comando e não mais opção.

Answer (score 1):

Significar as opções de fim de comando. Após o traço/hiffen duplos somente parâmetros posicionais são aceitos.

No seu exemplo, o grep pesquisará a string "-v" em todos os arquivos do diretório.

Se não usar o "--" o grep interpretaria o -v como opções do comando, que no caso do grep faz a inversão da busca, isto é, mostra o que não da match.